# Converting image URL to .png file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, axios, png

I am currently working on an application which takes in image URLs in this format:

```
https://replicate.delivery/pbxt/Y45OPyjFe92FLqemk1Mmsr69gzruylefj5SxKqJInMmxCyABB/out-0.png
```

And need to send it to an API to check if it is explicit content. The issue is that the API only accepts .png or .jpg files and not an image URL. How can I convert this image URL into a sendable file?

This is what their docs say:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require("form-data");

const form = new FormData();
form.append("providers", 'amazon, google');
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("️ path/to/your/image.png"));

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.edenai.run/v2/image/explicit_content',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'Bearer  Your_API_Key',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form.getBoundary()
  },
  data: form
};

axios
  .request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

However, I do not have the path to the file and instead solely the image URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an extra request to get the image first, keep it in memory (alternatively, you could save the file and then read it with `fs`), and then make another request, which sends the image to the checking endpoint.

With `axios`, you can get the image as a `stream`, and then just pass it along with `form-data`.

Try this:

```
// get image as a stream
const getImgOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://replicate.delivery/pbxt/Y45OPyjFe92FLqemk1Mmsr69gzruylefj5SxKqJInMmxCyABB/out-0.png',
  responseType: 'stream'
};

let img;

try {

  img = await axios.request(getImgOptions);


  // got the image, now send it for checking
  let uploadImg;

  try {


    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("providers", 'amazon, google');
    form.append("file", img.data);

    const postImgOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://api.edenai.run/v2/image/explicit_content',
      headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer  Your_API_Key',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + form.getBoundary()
      },
      data: form
    };

    uploadImg = await axios.request(postImgOptions);
    // do something with the result
    console.log('check response: ', uploadImg.data);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```